# Cannot Restore Live Version of PowerApps application

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have been tasked with updating a PowerApps application that connects to a standard SharePoint list.  The Live version of the app (using PowerApps Release 3.19054.15) is stable and used frequently throughout the organisation without issue.

When starting to work, I discovered that a previous employee had made some changes of their own and saved (but not published) them to a newer version.  The changes appear to be incomplete (and buggy) compared to what's in the current live version.  More importantly, I don't know exactly what has changed.  As such, management want me to rollback whatever was done by that employee and to then do my own updates.

However, this doesn't seem to be possible - I cannot restore the "live" version of the application, as the "Restore" option is greyed out for this version.

I suspect Microsoft have disabled the rollback as the live version is a little old now(?).  Does Microsoft have an official guide that details the last version that is supported for rollback, at any given time?  Should I be able to rollback to any version regardless?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out to Microsoft, I was advised that "per the product design", we could not restore the older (6 month's old) version.  A suggested work around was to use the PowerApps Cmdlet `Restore-PowerAppVersion` (as documented in this [PowerShell support for PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell) page), with the caveat that the version may not work correctly, or at all.